# matching dates algorithm in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, date

We have MySQL table like this:

```
ON_FRIDAY bit(1)              //occurs on friday 1/0
ON_MONDAY bit(1) 
ON_SATURDAY bit(1) 
ON_SUNDAY bit(1) 
ON_THURSDAY bit(1) 
ON_TUESDAY bit(1) 
ON_WEDNESDAY bit(1) 
REPETITION_STARTS_FROM date    //valid from
WEEKLY_REPETITION int(11)      //1-4 1=every week 2=every second week 3=every third week 4=once a month
```

and have to create matching query for date like '2016-09-29'
which would match every record that occurs in same date as defined in the table

Example:

```
ON_FRIDAY 1
ON_MONDAY 0
ON_SATURDAY 0
ON_SUNDAY 0 
ON_THURSDAY 0 
ON_TUESDAY 0
ON_WEDNESDAY 1 
REPETITION_STARTS_FROM '2016-08-23'
WEEKLY_REPETITION 3     //every third week
```

Matched days for this example (return true):
24.8.
26.8.
14.9.
16.9.
5.10.
7.10.
and so on

Any idea how to solve this problem ?
I am not looking for exact SQL query but idea how to solve it.

Comment: What did you try? You cannot expect us to work for you :)

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out.

At first I am counting number of weeks since some date like this:

```
cast((datediff(date_sub(repetition_starts_from, interval (dayofweek(repetition_starts_from) - 2) day), '2014-01-01') / 7) as unsigned) as weeks

cast((datediff(date_sub(SEARCHED_DATE, interval (dayofweek(SEARCHED_DATE) - 2) day), '2014-01-01') / 7) as unsigned) as weeks
```

then I calculate modulus for both values like this:

```
weeks % weekly_repetition
```

if this modulus is the same for both dates, then I know that I am in week where both dates can match and last thing is to figure out if day of week is matching like this for all days in week:

```
case when dayofweek(SEARCHED_DATE) = 1 and on_monday = 1 then 1 else 0 end
```

If anyone has more elegant approach be my guest.